# Fill Tool ignores Grease Pencil Lines?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I am using the 2D Animation function of blender. I have Grease Pencil lines drawn on a number of layers and I am trying to fill the area inside these lines using the Fill Tool on a new layer. However the fill tool seems to ignore the lines and fills the whole visible screen. What is strange is if I zoom out the window the fill tool will work sometimes, and other times it fills the whole screen again. This is seemingly at random.

For the life of me I can't figure this out. I have tried "construction" lines, drawing on the same layer as the grease pencil lines, using shift-click with the fill tool, changing the Leak size, the material thickness, watched tutorials. The strangest thing is the tool worked completely fine in another project, but this is the second project I have created that has this problem. I even updated from 2.9.01 to 2.91.

I am sure I am messing something up in the settings. I am still new to blender. But this is driving me crazy! Please help!

https://streamable.com/zqixi5

Answer (score 0):

This Sounds like you have a gap and hence filling the screen. This depends allot on your line and Fill thickness/leakage thickness. The reason it's filling from a distance is the fill resolution/ thickness/ leakage is relative so a tiny gap when zoomed in disappears when you zoom out.

The gap might be tiny but heres some options for you;

- turn up the fill resolution (in advanced drop down). I keep mine at 3 or the fill shape sucks.
- increase your fill tool leakage size
- Join your strokes to remove gaps. Select the strokes and use ctrl J.
- If you only have 1 stroke use F to auto close it.

One of those should sort your issue.
Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: the above answer by Matt is correct, although turning up the settings never worked for me. I contacted the developers and they gave some extra information:

- Grease Pencil strokes have thickness but are attached to 2d wires with no thickness. (Seen in edit mode) These wires must be LESS THAN 1/2 the Stroke thickness away from another 'wire' to consider the leak closed.
- The fill tool uses pixel information to fill an area, which changes with the zoom level. This causes the leak to 'open' and 'close' based on zoom. (In the future this may be changed to a boolean method)

Thank you Matt!